# Get specific section of AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

When i inspect the response from my AJAX request to index.php, I get back some data that i want (some json, a return value i need the value of) but also a load of HTML as the index.php class is used to call a view which is responsible for loading up some HTML.

Here is the first two lines of the response:

```
{"returnVal":"registered"}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

Due to my code being MVC, i cannot just create a separate file to handle the AJAX request, so i need a way for my login.js class (where the AJAX request is generated) to go through the whole response and find the value of "returnVal" that I need. Do you know of a way I can do this?

Login.js

```
var loginData, urlPath;

// Allow users to log in or register
function Login() {

    if(!document.getElementById("usernameField")) { // If we have no username field on this page, we are just logging in
        loginData = "email=" + $("#emailField").val() + "&password=" + $("#passwordField").val() + "&action=" + "loggingIn";
        urlPath = "index.php";
    } else { // we are registering
        loginData = "username=" + $("#usernameField").val() + "&email=" + $("#emailField").val() + "&password=" + $("#passwordField").val() + "&action=" + "register";
        urlPath = "../index.php";
    }

    // Send the login/registration data to database
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlPath,
            data: loginData,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result); // i need to get the value of 'returnVal' from the response

                if(result.returnVal=="registered") {
                    document.getElementById('notification').innerHTML = "You have been registered";
                } else if (result.returnVal=="username") {
                    document.getElementById('notification').innerHTML = "Username already taken";
                } else if (result.returnVal=="email") {
                    document.getElementById('notification').innerHTML = "Email already taken";
                } else if (result.returnVal=="notRegistered") {
                    document.getElementById('notification').innerHTML = "Please enter registered email";
                } else if (result.returnVal=="loginFail") {
                    document.getElementById('notification').innerHTML = "Please enter correct password";
                } else if (result.returnVal=="loggedIn") {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    document.getElementById('loginButton').innerHTML = "Account Settings";
                } else { // Something wrong, tell us
                    //alert(result);
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }

        })
    })
}
```

index.php

```
<?php 
    ini_set("log_errors", 1);

    require_once("Model/model.php");
    require_once("Controller/controller.php");
    require_once("View/view.php");

    $model = new Model();
    $view = new View();
    $controller = new Controller($model, $view);

    if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
            if($_POST['action'] == "register") {
                $controller->Register($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
                echo json_encode($controller->GetReturned());
            }
    }

    $view->Begin();
?>
```

Comment: you defenitely should do it the other way round: call a script that is _not_ returning html. I don't know what framework you use, but maybe there's also an api-route available?

Comment: but one (messy) way would be to just delete everything start from "<!DOCTYPE" and then JSON.parse the rest (=your json string)

Comment: only load the view if you aren't sending the json by adding else or use a flag for no view and check flag

Comment: what if you just leave out the last `$view->Beginn();`?

Comment: @Jeff `$view->Begin();` returns a HTML view.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez yes, and he doesn't need/want the HTML view here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultra simple way is just `exit()` after you echo the json so the view never gets sent. If this controller is never intended to render a view get rid of `$view->Begin();`

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
       if($_POST['action'] == "register") {
             $controller->Register($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
                echo json_encode($controller->GetReturned());
                exit();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a (messy but still) way to extract the data you need.
But please consider my first comment. You should do it the other way round.

```
var result = '{"returnVal":"registered"}<!DOCTYPE html>someother grap';
var n = result.indexOf("<!DOCTYPE");
var jsonString = input.substring(0, n);
var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(json);
// your values are here:
// json.returnVal;
```

This relies on the strict convention, that every return has a '